# maximum scrollback size of "screen" window manager

Tags: gnu-screen, scrolling

The ["screen" window manager](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Scrollback) allows specifying the desired size of the scrollback buffer.

E.g. when starting a new session: ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen))

> ```
> ‘-h num’
>     Set the history scrollback buffer to be num lines high.
>     Equivalent to the defscrollback command (see Copy).
> ```

Or when already inside a screen session with these commands: ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Scrollback))

> ```
> 12.1.2 Scrollback
> — Command: defscrollback num
>            Same as the scrollback command except that the default
>            setting for new windows is changed. Defaults to 100. 
> — Command: scrollback num
>            Set the size of the scrollback buffer for the current 
>            window to num lines. The default scrollback is 100 lines.
>            Use C-a i to view the current setting.
> ```

But I cannot seem to find documentation stating the maximum value for `num` for any of above approaches.

So the question is: how to determine the maximum scrollback length for the screen utility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where to find it documented, but digging into the source a bit gives some clues.  When you pass in `-h` it sets the `histheight` (see [screen.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/screen.c)).  In `main` it parses `-h` as follows:

```
case 'h':
    if (--argc == 0)
        exit_with_usage(myname, NULL, NULL);
    nwin_options.histheight = atoi(*++argv);
    if (nwin_options.histheight < 0)
        exit_with_usage(myname, "-h: %s: negative scrollback size?", *argv);
    break;
```

The `nwin_options` struct is an instance of `NewWindow` which is defined in [window.h](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/tree/src/window.h):

```
struct NewWindow {
    int StartAt;    /* where to start the search for the slot */
    char    *aka;       /* aka string */
    char    **args;     /* argv vector */
    char    *dir;       /* directory for chdir */
    char    *term;      /* TERM to be set instead of "screen" */
    bool    aflag;
    bool    dynamicaka;
    int flowflag;
    int lflag;
    int histheight;
    int monitor;
    int wlock;      /* default writelock setting */
    int silence;
    bool    wrap;
    bool    Lflag;      /* logging */
    int slow;       /* inter character milliseconds */
    int gr;
    bool    c1;
    int bce;
    int encoding;
    char    *hstatus;
    char    *charset;
    int poll_zombie_timeout;
};
```

where we can see that `histheight` is an int, so presumably the max value you can set it to is `maxint` for a signed int.

Comment: :-) crosspost. Thanks Eric, yous is a bit more factual answer.

Comment: It seems the maximum value can differ per system. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855459/maximum-value-of-int) is a Q&A that deals with actually determining it on a system.

Comment: @PaulvanLeeuwen and make sure you're using the same compiler as `screen` was compiled with.  For example, if you did the test with a 64-bit compiler, but `screen` was compiled with 32-bit one, your value would be way off

Answer (score 2):

While trying to answer my own question, this is what I found on my own system via trial-and-error:

**answer: there is a hard-limit (somewhere between 50,000,000 and 1,000,000,000), but performance will probably be your bottleneck (as such I was not able to determine the exact hard-limit)**

My experiments included:

Start a new screen session without having any `~/.screenrc` configuration file:

```
screen -a
```

Inside screen open the screen command prompt by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>:</kbd> and enter the command:

```
scrollback 1000000
```

which resulted in the message: `scrollback set to 1000000` (1,000,000).

Trying `scrollback 1000000000` (1,000,000,000) quite quickly resulted in the message `scrollback set to 0`. I assume this means that 1,000,000 is accepted and 1,000,000,000 is too much.

Trying `scrollback`100000000` (100,000,000) made screen hang. A second terminal session and some patience later I was able to kill screen. This behavior turned out to be consistent when trying the same thing again.

Trying `scrollback 10000000` (10,000,000) with 2 seconds delay resulted in the message `scrollback set to 10000000`.

Trying `scrollback 50000000` (50,000,000) with 60 seconds delay resulted in the message `scrollback set to 50000000`.